# Phonegap with Angular - directives not showing and strange view display

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am trying to build a Phonegap application using Angular.js

**I am trying to this:** When a user logs in, a heading will be displayed to the user.

I have directive in `directive.js` :

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('ngHeaderline', ['Auth', function(Auth) {
  return {
    templateUrl: '/views/partials/header.html',

    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    link: function($scope) {
      $scope.isAuthenticated = Auth.isLoggedIn;
      $scope.logout = Auth.logout();
    }
  }
}]);
```

And let's presume all the elements are there. Auth factory and the template (everything is displaying fine when I test it on Chrome browser)

And then in my `index.html` I have:

```
 <body>


<div ng-headerline></div>

    <div class="main-content">
        <div ng-errorline></div>
        <div ng-loadingline></div>
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

  <!-- Foundation JS dependencies -->

  <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>


    <script src="scripts/vendor/cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery.formatDateTime/jquery.formatDateTime.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>




    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>

</body>
```

And my `header.html` partial looks like this:

```
<div class="app">

<div ng-show="isAuthenticated()">
My Header
</div>

</div>
```

To repeat, everything is showing correctly when I est it on browser, but when I compile with Phonegap and deploy to the Android device, header is not showing.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same exact problem actually.  Your problem is here:

```
templateUrl: '/views/partials/header.html',
```

You need to remove that initial slash and use a relative path.  In my case I had '/scripts/directives/templates/bottom-menu.html' and my template did not work.  I removed the first slash and it worked perfectly.

The reason is that when it's deployed to android these files are no longer in the root directory, so that first slash breaks the path.

Comment: Yes, precisely. I have came to exact same solution, but I didn't have time to post it here. Thanks for letting me know and for others to see.

Comment: You gave me the hint but in my case the issue was a bit different, I was loading the file with the directive name 'searchResults.js' in my index file, but it turns out the physical file was 'SearchResults.js'. The browser didn't care about that uppercase difference and was working without problems. But Android was not loading the directive at all because of the filename difference. I leave it as reference in case someone experience the same.